# Dynamic OSGi service replacement as development aid

Tags: java, osgi, apache-felix

We are using Apache Felix annotations to handle all the OSGi stuff in our application. I have a provider class that talks to a server. I have a consumer class that does stuff with data from the server. What I want is to create another provider instance (new class implementing interface) that is for debug purposes only that returns canned responses to requests by the consumer. Ideally I would like the consumer to be unaware of this handoff. It's provider service reference would simply be replaced.

**The use case**: When the developer is running on a machine without access to the actual server, he presses a button in our running app to switch from the real provider instance to our debug provider instance.

What is the recommended way to accomplish this?

Example code:

```
public interface IProvider{
    public String getDataFromServer();
}


@Component
@Service(value=IProvider.class)
public class RealProvider implements IProvider{
    @Override
    public String getDataFromServer(){
        ...
    }
}


@Component
@Service(value=IProvider.class)
public class DebugProvider implements IProvider{
    @Override
    public String getDataFromServer(){
        return "Hello World";
    }
}


@Component
public class Consumer{
    private @Reference IProvider provider;

    public void doSomething(){
        provider.getDataFromServer();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the two providers are in separate bundles, you can stop Bundle A and start Bundle B to switch between implementations of the service.

If the two providers are in the same bundle, you'd need to either drop down to the OSGI API  and register/unregister the services manually, or create a proxy version of IProvider that has a debugMode flag and delegates to the specific implementation.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with hos to register or unregister a service manually using the OSGI API. So far we have used Felix annotations for everything. Can you point me to a source that explains it? Thanks for the help.

Comment: http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-tutorial-example-2.html 

BUT because you are using the Apache Felix SCR Annotations, you would use @Activate and get the ComponentContext/BundleContext that way, rather than writing an 'Activator'.

Comment: I would also suggest figuring out how you would solve this /without/ OSGI.

Comment: As of right now my DebugProvider and RealProvider live in the same bundle but they will be split up eventually. I looked into the OSGI API and found a call to disable a component so long as the named component is in the same bundle. Rather than do a temporary solution I opted instead to have the Consumer aware of what mode we are in. The consumer gets references to both the RealProvider and DebugProvider (which still implements IProvider but registers in OSGi under an IDebugProvider interface). The Consumer then uses the appropriate IProvider instance based on the requested mode. It works fine